# Enum Forward Declaration

Tags: c++, enums, forward-declaration

I'm trying to correctly use a forward declaration for enums. Therefore I searched the Internet, but I can't find something that works.

I'm using this in a header:

```
// Forward declaration
enum myEnumProcessState;
```

I'm then using this enum in a struct:

```
struct myStruct {
    [...]
    myEnumProcessState osState;
    [...]
};
```

And in another header:

```
enum myEnumProcessState {
    eNotRunning,
    eRunning
};
```

I found out that the type should be put in the enum forward declaration to be accepted. However, I don't know which "type" I should put for a Process State. These don't work:

```
enum myEnumProcessState : unsigned int;
enum myEnumProcessState : String;
```

I wanted to skip the forward declaration, but my *struct* is crying since it can't find it any more...

So I'm a bit confused. Is there a solution?

Comment: why do you need to forward declare it? can't you just define it before you use it (that is, include the file that has the enum / move the enum to a file that can be included by both files)?

Comment: Well ... it DOES work. However I really would have wanted to do it with a forward declaration.
Now, if the only "clean" solution is to skip it, I will ...

Comment: I actually don't know if there is a solution to this.. I however fail to see the reason why you would want to do it..

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Before C++11, C++ didn't support forward-declaration of enums at all! However, some compilers (like MS Visual Studio) provide language extensions for that.

If your compiler doesn't support C++11, look in its documentation on enum forward declarations.

If you can use C++11, there is the `enum class` syntax (you almost got it right, but pay attention to the additional `class` keyword:

```
// Forward declaration
enum class myEnumProcessState: unsigned int;

// Usage in a struct
struct myStruct {myEnumProcessState osState;};

// Full declaration in another header
enum class myEnumProcessState: unsigned int {
    eNotRunning,
    eRunning
};

// Usage of symbols (syntax may seem slightly unusual)
if (myObject.osState == myEnumProcessState::eNotRunning) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Hm. When I put this, I got a "error : expected '{' before ';' token on the ligne

    "enum class myEnumProcessState : unsigned int;"

...

Comment: It seems your compiler supports c++03 but not c++11. Forward declarations for enums are not supported in c++03, but some compilers do support them as a language extension (whether or not you should use these extensions is a whole other can of worms).

Comment: It's G++ 4.7.2, I thought it followed C++11 by default. Doesn't it ?

Comment: Well ... it doesn't. I added -std=c++11 and now it does

Comment: `enum class` is not required for this, and nor is it always desirable. A plain `enum` can be forward-declared so long as the underlying type is specified. Having said that, the precise details are currently unclear to me. You'd assume a plain enum declared without an explicit underlying type would get `int`, but I'm getting a "type mismatch" error... not that it's kind enough to tell me what type it _thinks_ my original untyped declaration was specifying. :S Presumably, explicitly specifying the underlying type at both the full and forward declaration sites is safest/required.